# Non Collapsible TreePanel in GXT

Tags: gxt, treepanel

I am new to GXT and need a little help in implementing a tree panel.
User has a requirement that the TreePanel should not allowed to be collapsed and it should always remain expanded. (as in the image)[image]
Is there a way we can achieve this ? May be using some other widget ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can use on your tree `addCollapseHandler()` which will always call `tree.setExpanded(true);`